# onLayout not being called when component is rendered

Tags: react-native

In order to get the position of a component within it's parent, am using `onLayout()`.
However, the method is not being called when the component is rendered, and the example below does not log to the console.

```
<MyComponent
   key={index}
   onLayout={(event) => {
      const {width, height, x y} = event.nativeEvent.layout
      console.log('width', width)
      console.log('height', height)
      console.log('x', x)
      console.log('y', y)
  }}
/>
```

What is the correct way to get the position?

Thanks

Comment: Typo? There's no comma between `x y}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onLayout method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout) has a nativeEvent which is type of [LayoutEvent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutevent). You can use it to access layout properties.

```
onLayout={(event) => {
  const {width, height, x y} = event.nativeEvent.layout
  console.log('width', width)
  console.log('height', height)
  console.log('x', x)
  console.log('y', y)
}}
```

Comment: How is that different than the code in the question? Because no log is being output to the console in the example, my understanding is onLayout is not being called.

Comment: event.target.measure? event object has no property called measure.